# In XML, is value="[PASSWORD]" a hardcoded password?

Tags: xml, security, password-protection

I have searched but cannot find an answer to what should be a pretty simple question: Is the following a hardcoded password?

```
<system-properties>
  <property name="javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword" value="[PASSWORD]"
</system-properties>
```

The code also uses 
    keystore-password="[PASSWORD]" 
    truststore-password="[PASSWORD]"

I am reviewing code for vulnerabilities, so I cannot rewrite the code.

Thank you!

Comment: I saw a question in my inbox but it disappeared when I clicked on it. The question asked if "PASSWORD" was a real password. The code is exactly how I typed it. The word PASSWORD is in the code, in square brackets, in double quotes.

Comment: This question is nothing to do with XML. You have a file here which means something (presumably) to some application, and what it means is a matter of application convention. For all we know, the token "[PASSWORD]" means "You won't find the password here, you will have to look somewhere else", and if that is the case, there is clearly no vulnerability.

Comment: Thank you. I had not considered that the word could just be a redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML itself doesn't care whether a password is hardcoded or not, but clearly if you're storing passwords unencrypted in an XML file, it's a security risk, as it would be for any file format.

Comment: Yes, kjhughes, but I do not know if the square brackets mean that the value comes off of a stack or is possibly pulled from somewhere else. Or are the brackets meaningless? Does this line really mean that someone hardcoded the word "PASSWORD" as an unencrypted (and patently simple) password? (I did not write the code, I am just reviewing it for vulnerabilities.)

Comment: I'd assumed that you replaced the actual password with the string, `[PASSWORD]`.  If it literally is `[PASSWORD]` in the XML file, then it would appear to be a placeholder.  If the actual value used is an unencrypted password, then, yes, there's a security risk, as I answered.  There is no significance at the XML level of an attribute value surrounded by brackets.  That's merely a user or application convention.

Comment: No, that is exactly how the line of code appears. So this is actually a hardcoded, 8 character password of "PASSWORD". The brackets confused me. Thank you.

Comment: I did note that it likely is a placeholder.